# SharePoint online authantication when using SharePointOnlineCredentials

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

When I connect to SharePoint online using SharePointOnlineCredentials what type of authentication am I using? I don't think it is oauth.

Also the legacy authentication is being discontinued by MS. So will this way still work after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how this will work, you will register an Azure AD app with the appropriate Graph API permissions (there is also the v1 API which uses Client ID/Secret, registered in SharePoint itself).

See [Using CSOM for .NET Standard instead of CSOM for .NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#configuring-an-application-in-azure-ad).

See [SharePoint authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/authentication) for how SharePoint Online auth is performed. Essentially, you're issued a FedAuth cookie.

Comment: When passing the user and pwd to the clientcontext no browser interaction is present. Am I using oauth in this scenario or Federated authentication with AAD as the IDP? How does this relate to the legacy authentication setting in my tenant?

Comment: Disabling Legacy Auth (which you should do along with disabling App Passwords) prevents the use of non-modern authentication mechanisms. But programmatically you shouldn't be using username/password, at least for non-interactive scenarios.

Comment: We are using Azure AD app registrations for our non interactive stuff. I'm building a test case because we are having issues with PnP-PowerShell using the credential manager. When we execute a specific cmdlet and use the credential manager we get invalid refresh token errors. PnP also uses username and password from credential manager to build the clientcontext. So I want to test it using plain CSOM. I was just looking how authentication goes when using CSOM and passing SharePointOnlineCredentials.