# SharePoint Online Authentication Types how do they work

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I am trying to figure out how the different authentication types in SharePoint online work. I am doing this research because I want check the impact of disabling legacy authentication in my tenant. This is a follow up on my question [Question about SharePoint online credentials](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286697/sharepoint-online-authantication-when-using-sharepointonlinecredentials)

Based on this image

[image: SharePoint online authentication types]

As far as I know these are the types we currently use.

When logging in from the browser:

1. ADFS (on-prem accounts)
2. Cloud Authentication using Cloud only account -> Azure AD as IDP

When logging in from code

1. From code using SharePoint online credentials
2. Using an Azure AD App registration

When I use ADFS I use federated authentication. I see that 2 cookies are set by SharePoint. These cookies are named "FedAuth" and "rtFa".

Question 1:
When legacy authentication is disabled, cookie based authentication is disabled. So will ADFS still work?

Question 2:
When I use cloud only accounts, am I still using federated authentication? is Azure AD used as the ADFS server? Or am I authenticated against Azure AD using other authentication type? Because in this situation I also see these cookies  "FedAuth" and "rtFa" being set.

Question 3
When I connect from code using CSOM

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/"))  
{  
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I see this authentication flow

[image: Authentication flow]

A cookie named "SPOIDCRL" is created and used as authentication (I can use this in Postman for example) What kind of authentication is this? A SAML token is send to the srf endpoint and I am authenticated using the idcrl.svc endopint.

This authentication type (SharePoint online credentials) stops working when I disable legacy authentication.

Using the Azure AD app registration is clear to me.